# File selection (camera, gallery picker etc) not working in Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider

1. List item

I have an existing market place version of the app working fine with all other android versions. But recently I noticed that the image upload features of my application (through both gallery and camera) doesn't work on my phone (recently upgraded to Nougat). On debugging i noticed that the code breaks in the below point

```
 ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uriImage.toString());
```

Although uriImage seems to have a valid url. (value
I confirmed this by doing  new File(uriImage.toString()) and it seems to be working fine.
The value of uriImage.toString() at this point is..

I had search the internet for this and found no results. Although i suspect the Nougat behaviour explained in the link below. I have made the changes suggested by the author, but the issue persists.  Below is my code for triggering the camera/picker intents

```
      public static Uri startChooseImage(Activity parent, String tag, String message, boolean useCamera, int requestId)
  {
   Uri uriImage =  FileProvider.getUriForFile(parent,
           "com.dyt.fileprovider",
           new File(
                   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + tag));
/*    Uri uriImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(
      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + tag));*/
    Intent selIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.PICK").setType("image/*");
    selIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    selIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(selIntent, message);
    if (useCamera) {
      List<Intent> intentsList = new ArrayList();
      Intent camIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
      camIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
      camIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      PackageManager pm = parent.getPackageManager();
      List<ResolveInfo> listCam = pm.queryIntentActivities(camIntent, 0);
      for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        Intent finalIntent = new Intent(camIntent);
        finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

        finalIntent.putExtra("output", uriImage);
        intentsList.add(finalIntent);
      }
      chooserIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INITIAL_INTENTS", 
        (Parcelable[])intentsList.toArray(new Parcelable[intentsList.size()]));
    }
    parent.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, requestId);
    return uriImage;
  }
```

Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: `uriImage.toString()`. Please tell its value.

Comment: There is no uploading code in your post nor code where the exif interface cide line is used.

Comment: `code breaks in the below point`. What is 'code breaks'?

Comment: "Although uriImage seems to have a valid url" -- neither the platform `ExifInterface` (which you should not be using) or the support library `ExifInterface` take a URL value in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

// add in app manifest file

```
<provider
        android:authorities="com.package.name"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:readPermission="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/image_path">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

// image path define in new xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<external-path
    name="images"
    path="Android/data/Apppackagename/files/Pictures"/>
```